# Twin paradox without accelaration, having been together or making any semblance of a roundtrip

Tags: special-relativity

I'm an alien. I communicate with people on earth by radio signal with the following dialogue.

"Hi my name is Zork. We measure time with microwaved cesium atoms. Just out of curiosity did you know that motion is relative and speed of light is the max velocity? Also I see by your doppler shift that we're not moving relative to each other, agreed? Please respond quickly after receiving this message so I can measure our distance accurately."

"Hi my name is Steven. We measure time with microwaved cesium as well. 9,192,631,770 X 3600 X 24 cycles is called 1day for us. I'm responding to your message less than 1day from when I received it. Yes we know motion is relative and light is the max velocity and details thereof. And I agree we're not moving relative to each other. So what's on your mind?"

"Wow I received your reply 2000 days after I sent my message. That means we are 1000 lightdays from each other. Here's what's going on, an alien named Gong broadcasted me a message a while back. He said he seems to be on a course past me and right past you as well. He doesn't know anything about having accelerated but he's headed toward me, and eventually you, at 50% the speed of light. He'll pass by me in 1010days (so 10 days after you receive this message). I'll tell him of your 1day unit. When Gong passes me he'll reset his microwave-cesium stopwatch to 0. Please do the same 10days from when you receive this message. When he passes you please each tell each other the number of days on your stopwatch."

No one accelerated, they were never together and no one made a u-turn. So who's stopwatch is at 1000 days and who's stopwatch is at 845 days, Steven's or Gong's?

Comment: I am voting to close. This needs to be way more focused. The color of skin and size of nose are irrelevant distractions. Also, the focused version of this question is probably a duplicate

Comment: I'm being massacred. I guess a mistake like this is an easy target for down votes. Can someone please delete this question?

Comment: @JoeC downvotes can be cruel- I got a storm of them not long ago on the main meta site for complaining about captchas- but they are only marks on a webpage, so best to just be thick-skinned about them!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how this is a twin paradox situation. You simply have two synchronized clocks a distance $L$ apart and at rest with respect to one-another, and a moving clock which goes from one to the other at speed $v$.  As measured by the clocks at rest, the journey takes a time $T = L/v$. As measured by the moving clock, the journey takes a time $T' = T\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$, and so $T'<T$.

Comment: How does anyone know that the clock that passed me and the earthling is the clock that is moving? How do you know that the earthing and I are not the ones moving?

Comment: @JoeC it doesn’t matter who is moving and who is not. Two Einstein-synchronized clocks will always record a greater difference than a single clock that meets both. All frames can distinguish the two synchronized clocks from one clock

Comment: @JoeC Dale's comment sums it up nicely. By moving, I mean moving with respect to the two clocks.

Comment: A very common misconception in SR is that a moving clock runs slower than a stationary one, which leads to the obvious question of how to tell which one is moving. The time dilation formula applies when two physically separated clocks moving inertially in turn pass one clock also moving inertially.  The interval between the two encounters is always longer according to the two clocks than it is according to the one clock that meets each of them...

Comment: ...so the formula applies only in a non-symmetrical situation in which one clock in one frame is compared with two clocks in another. There is no question about which frame 'is moving'. You can declare either to be the stationary frame, but always the time according to the single clocks is less than the time according to the two clocks in the other frame.

Comment: Why couldn't I just get Marco's answer instead of down votes? He said it's a common misconception. I think there are some people who out there who thought what I thought and learned from what Marco said.

Comment: @JoeC I did not downvote your question, but if I had to guess I would say that downvotes were attracted due to the story you wrapped around your question, which served mostly to obfuscate what you were actually trying to ask. Try not to take them personally - of the 37 people who viewed your question, 4 of them elected to downvote it. It's not a big deal.

Comment: When people write "Clock A" and "Clock B" and "Event C" I always see answers about how Clock A and B must have been together when they got synced so Clock B must have accelerated to get 1000 lightdays away etc... My story makes it crystal clear and relatable that none of these clocks where ever together or accelerated. I've seen videos on Youtube with millions of views about "Alice and Bob" examples. But yes I knew I was taking a chance when I added the part about not having a nose. The main point was they they had no common ancestry, their particles were never together since the big bang.

Comment: @JoeC The context in which you saw that clocks $A$ and $B$ had to be together to be synchronized has to do with the Einstein synchronization convention, which relies on the notion that the speed of light is the same in all directions. This is a subtle and more involved idea, but this fact itself is conventional rather than physical. That is, an anisotropic speed of light is physically indistinguishable from using a reference frame in which the clocks at different locations are synchronized in a different way. This isn't the subject of your question, however.